# Any way to exports a generator function?

Tags: javascript, generator, koa, co

An example

`generator.js`:

```
exports.read = function *(){
  var a = yield read('co.github.js');
  var b = yield read('co.recevier.js');
  var c = yield read('co.yield.js');
  console.log([a,b,c]);
}

function read(file) {
  return function(fn){
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', fn);
  }
}
```

`co.js`:

```
var co = require('co');
var fs = require('fs');
var gen = require('./generator')
/*function read(file) {
  return function(fn){
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', fn);
  }
}*/

co(gen.read)()
```

It seems that `exports` doesn't support generator function.

```
require, module, __filename, __dirname) { module.exports.read = function *(){
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1027:3
```

Why I want to do this? I just want to separate my data from Controllers. Any way to solve it?

Comment: Isn't that error saying something else?

Comment: Nope. It seems the require in node doesn't support generator.

Comment: What's the * in the function definition? It's invalid javascript - which is what the error is complaining about

Comment: It's generator function defined in ES6. V8 has supported it.

Comment: Are you using --harmony flag?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a variable to store it, and export it afterwards :

```
var myGenerator = function *() {
    // ...
}

module.exports = myGenerator;
```

In another file, then, you can `require` it :

```
var myGen = require('./myfirstfile.js');
// myGen is now myGenerator from above
```

Answer (score 2):

you can export whatever you want, but please do not export generator functions in public modules. generators are control flow hacks. instead, return promises with `co@4`

```
exports.fn = co.wrap(function* () {
  return yield something() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the issue:

[NodeJS console SyntaxError: Unexpected token * for generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444366/nodejs-console-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-for-generator)

Furthermore, I would not export anything that is not an object, specially in ES6 having classes at your disposal.