# NodeJS console SyntaxError: Unexpected token * for generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

I am running the NodeJS console:

```
$ node --version
v0.12.0
```

And I am trying to implement a Generator function such as this one

```
function* colorGen() {
    var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "white"]
    var i = 0;
    yield colors[i];
    i += 1;
    if (i > 3) {i = 0;}  
}
```

But when I run the first line, I get a syntax error:

```
$ node
> function* colorGen() {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try it without "*" ?

Comment: check if this other post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12

Comment: Like tehnuty says, delete the asterisk.  Maybe you're a C/C++ coder--like me--who just needs more coffee.

Comment: The [asterisk is required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to define a generator function. The syntax is just new and not always supported.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generator functions are currently available in node behind a flag `--harmony_generators`. See [Features Implemented in V8 and Available in Node](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ES6-%28a.k.a.-Harmony%29-Features-Implemented-in-V8-and-Available-in-Node).

Answer (score 4):

Functions with asterisk are in ECMAScript 6 syntax.

```
function* name()
```

I think your nodejs can't recognize it. Use `--harmony` flag, when you start your server.